# Is it correct to use "might assuredly" because they seem paradoxical to me

Tags: meaning

Is "might assuredly" in this sentence meaningful, or a self-contradictory, as I suspect?

> Requiring students to take imaginative literature **might assuredly** result from the good intention of colleges to erudite their students comprehensively.

Comment: That whole sentence is on fire, let's worry more about the roof than the armchair.  "Erudite" as a verb? This whole thing was put into a blender with a thesaurus and then glopped back out. I wish people would [use $5 words sparingly](https://books.google.com/books?id=h4qDCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT1460&ots=mkLqix1eRt&dq=%22account%20of%20some%20single%20irradiating%20word.%22.%22&pg=PT1460#v=onepage&q=%22account%20of%20some%20single%20irradiating%20word.%22.%22&f=false), or not at all. Attempts to stuff a sentence full of them always turn into a mess.

Comment: @Dan Bron You don't mince words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see what you did there!

Comment: @Dan Bron But you seem to mix metaphors.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your puns are getting dicey.

Comment: @Dan Bron When you're on a roll ...

Comment: I see no (self-)contradiction, but indeed, an undoubtedly well-meant penchant for sesquipedalian wordsmithery.

Comment: 'Assuredly' is appearing in its _pragmatic marker: modal (ie comment on speaker's confidence in statement's accuracy)_ capacity. (Traditionally, a 'sentence adverbial'.) It is interesting that a post-modal-verb position is fairly normal. But 'requiring students ...' as a subject for 'might ... result' is at best clunky.

Answer (score 1):

It  seems  paradoxical because "might" suggests uncertainty, might or might not, but "assuredly" implies the speaker is certain about something. Being sure that something might happen is not the same as being sure that it did happen.

> Angry Father:  How did this window get broken?
>
> Boy:  Maybe Grandma was throwing stones at it.

The father may respond to the boy's suggestion

> I'm not sure Grandma is strong enough. She might be.

At this point the man accepts that a broken window **might** result from   Grandma throwing stones, but he is not actually  sure whether it could or not.

The man  would then  perform a series of  calculations using appropriate assumptions for Grandma's strength, the density of stone  and the strength of glass. At  the end of this he is absolutely sure that Grandma throwing stones could cause a broken window. He can now say that the broken window **might assuredly** result from Grandma throwing stones.

However, under interrogation, Grandma may produce an alibi,  claiming  she'd been sitting by the fire all afternoon with  Aunt Ethel.  Grandma may even attempt to "frame" her grandson by claiming to have seen him kicking his football against the house shortly before the unfortunate incident took place.

Even though a broken window might assuredly result from Grandma throwing stones, that does not mean  that she actually did throw stones. There are other possible explanations which also might assuredly be the cause.  Eventually the father's  ageist and sexist attitudes  may lead to  the boy getting the blame anyway.

In OPs example, the point at issue is: "what is the reason that colleges require students to study imaginative literature?". The author is clear that the good intentions of the colleges is a perfectly  possible explanation. He is not arguing that this could not possibly be the reason, he concedes that it might assuredly be the reason. However that does not prove that it actually is the true reason. Perhaps the professors just prefer teaching it, or the college is influenced by some other considerations.  We would need to read on, but the author may be proposing another reason that also might assuredly be the reason for colleges teaching imaginative literature, and which, in his opinion, is more likely to be true.